# MySQL returns all select instead of output variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Found extremely simple example which will represent this behaviour:

```
DECLARE Existing INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name FROM users WHERE id = pid LIMIT 1;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO Existing;
Select Existing;
```

This will return both selects, instead of just showing Existing (same for output variables).

I have a stored procedure that has hundreds selects, I want to only retrieve one information about the user which is decided based on all those different selects, etc.

I do not wish to get 3MB of useless data from DB, I just want 16 byte return, nothing else.

Is it possible with MySQL ? Some time I've decided to move to MySQL, and we've made a lot of preparation for architecture, servers, etc. a lot of months of work.

Now I want to transfer the stored procedure, but seems based on all other questions, that MySQL doesn't care about lean approach and returns all that data making stored procedures pretty much useless (at least when you've worked with big SQL Server databases using stored procedures / functions and everything work as you would expect, keep all the internal data, selects, etc. where it belongs, do not return it to the client).

I've found info that it should be supported by a client, but it is against any kind of programming best practices (i.e. sending MB od useless data between servers while you only need 4 bytes, main reason to use stored procedures instead of writing the code in i.e. C# (as you would have to make hundreds of calls to DB to get i.e. account overview)).

Am I missing something ?

I want to call stored procedure, that can make hundreds of calls to other stored procedure, process i.e. 100MB of data, and the return only output variables (i.e. 5 that providing overview of the account)...

We also have AI engine that is still using SQL Server, and in there well you cannot afford getting dozes of MB per entity if you have to do it millions of times per day. It would break the whole application...

Please only tell me if MySQL can output stored procedure result to selected variables. I do not care about megabytes of useless data to me. I am not asking about counts or anything else. I am talking about complicated logic, and I want to know only if MySQL can do what Microsoft SQL Server does? (Stored procedure returns output ant that is it, that is why you have output parameter, this is why stored procedure exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing the select if you don't want the results?  A simpler way to get the results is to use `count(*)`:

```
DECLARE Existing INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Existing FROM users WHERE id = pid;
```

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()` are specifically for the situation where you want the query to return results.

Comment: Select is to populate different variables used in different places. 

Select is for internal processing and cannot be returned in Stored Proc.


I.e. Energy company with 1m customers, with thousands of rows, thousands cases, procs, very complicated logic.

MySQL would return megabytes of data in that case. 


The question is, can MySQL just do what it supposed to do ? Stored Proc can have thousands of lines, dozens variables, and hundrends of selects FOR INTERNAL PROCESSING so it would return only the result.

Comment: How can you i.e. access from count string data that is required in IF statement so you could carry on with processing ???????

Comment: @Mike . . . If you put the data into variables or a temporary table, then it is not going to be "output" by the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks, however the platform due to its nature is doing up to few dozens of thousands operations per second. Temporary tables, well, I guess it would be too much of the hassle. 

I just start discovering that thing that I've thought that would be an SQL standard, are just Microsoft SQL features. 

Basically we can only go with Microsoft SQL and pay hefty price for accessing our data, or find something else. If MySQL cannot work at least with stored procs as Microsoft, then it is not something that we can use.